# Как правильно назвать документ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Приказ "О допуске к руководству тушением пожаров и проведением аварийно-спасательных работ" или "О допуске к руководству тушения пожаров и проведения аварийно-спасательных работ"

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:
**"О допуске к руководству тушением пожаров и проведением аварийно-спасательных работ"**

По этому вопросу [licey.net](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/782-32_osobennosti_upravleniya_v_russkom_yazyke.html) говорит следующее:

> ...Ошибки встречаются при употреблении существительного руководство.
>   Конструкция **руководство чем** используется, если слово употреблено в
>   значении «направляющая деятельность управления кем-либо, чем-либо», то
>   есть при указании на процесс (руководство действиями забастовщиков;
>   руководство таким большим заводом требует организаторского таланта).
>   Конструкция **руководство чего** характерна для тех случаев, когда
>   существительное выступает в значении «руководители; орган, управляющий
>   предприятием, организацией» (руководство отдела приняло решение
>   сократить число сотрудников вдвое).

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, следует чуть упростить конструкцию:

*Приказ "О допуске к руководству тушением пожаров и аварийно-спасательными работами"*

...руководство (чем?) тушением и работами.